# Remove last special character in r

Tags: r, regex

I have regex for separating words after 15 chars by escape character (\n). I need to remove last special character from string if ends with only one character (below example string ends with bracket).

```
m <- gregexpr(pattern = paste("(.{1,",15,"}\\b|.{",1,"})",sep = ""), text = txt, perl = TRUE)
split_txt = trimws(unlist(regmatches(x = txt, m = m)))
paste(split_txt, collapse = "\n")
```

This resulted into:

```
Client News V2\n(design, AI\n)
```

This should be required output:

```
Client News V2\n(design, AI)
```

Is there an easy way how to do that? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `txt`? `txt <- "Client News V2(design, AI)"`?

Comment: What does `\n` mean in that variable?  Is it literal, or is it your way of representing a newline character in a single line?

Comment: I interpreted your question in a way resulting in [this demo](http://rextester.com/TFS53903) ... don't know if this is what you have in mind.

Comment: Sorry, please formulate the requirements verbally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` with regex *\n(.)$*, which captures the last character following new line character, and replace the last two with it (i.e. remove the last new line character if it is followed by only another character at the end):

```
s = "Client News V2\n(design, AI\n)"
sub("\n(.)$", "\\1", s)
# [1] "Client News V2\n(design, AI)"
```

Comment: One question: Is there any way how can I remove all special characters (\n) in every brackets:
E.g.: Client (News\n) V2 (design, AI\n) --> Client (News) V2 (design, AI)

Comment: You could try `gsub("\n(?=[^(]*\\))", "", s, perl = T)` adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610585/remove-specific-characters-inside-parentheses-using-regex).